# Do I need to shutdown the executor at the onMessage method of a class that implements MessageListener class?

Tags: java, spring

I have a Java application that uses Spring framework. It is a listener app that gets messages from a certain source asynchronously using threads quite rapidly and will be saved into the database.

I am using the ExecutorService which is initialized in a Servlet Class and stored in a static variable that can be accessed by the `onMessage()` method.

What I want to know is if there's a need to shutdown the ExecutorService if I will always be getting messages. If it turns out that I need to shutdown the executor, where should I place it?

```
@Override
public void onMessage(Message message) {
    String msg = "";
    ExecutorService taskExecutor;

    try {
        taskExecutor = StartupServlet.taskManager.getExecutor();
        msg = extractMessage(message);
        taskExecutor.execute(new MessageTask(msg));
        // Where do I place taskExecutor.shutdown();? Doing so here will reject the succeeding tasks, which breaks the listener.
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I am using Spring Beans to initialize the threads and it is working fine. I am just not sure if I should shut it down or not at all.

```
<bean id="taskManager" class="com.company.threading.TaskManager">
    <property name="executor" ref="executorService"/>
</bean>

<bean id="executorService" 
      class="java.util.concurrent.Executors" 
      factory-method="newFixedThreadPool" 
      destroy-method="shutdown">
    <constructor-arg value="5"/>
</bean>
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that `com.company.threading.TaskManager` is your custom class you don't need to call `shutdown` inside `onMessage`, because if you do so you will not be able to handle other messages.

That you need to do is gracefully terminate your executor on Spring context closing

```
@Component
public class ContextClosedHandler implements ApplicationListener<ContextClosedEvent> {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("executorService")
    private ExecutorService executor;

    @Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(ContextClosedEvent event) {
        executor.shutdown();
        try {
            // define how much time to wait for the completion
            if (!executor.awaitTermination(15, TimeUnit.MINUTES)) { 
                List<Runnable> incompleteTask = executor.shutdownNow();
                // do that you want with them
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // handle or log exception
        }
    }
}
```

Also, I would suggest you do not use static objects to obtain executor instance like so `StartupServlet.taskManager.getExecutor()`. Let the Spring do it for you!

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("executorService")
private ExecutorService executor;
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Hello, sorry for the delayed response. This does seem helpful, but I do have questions as to how to implement this. How do I include the xml file here which contains `executorService`? Also, my `TaskManager` class is just a simple getter and setter for the `executor`. Where should I put this?

Do I have to explicitly close() the ApplicationContext to activate this event? If so, where should I do that if not in the onMessage event?

Comment: @Wax, if you're using standard maven directory layout,  xml files should be in the src/main/resources directory. Instead of using TaskManager I suggest to just inject executorService bean as showed in the answer.  You don't need explicitly call close method,  here you just register the listener,  Spring will call it itself.

Comment: The `executorService` is always `null` when trying out the `@Autowired` version. Why is that? I tried googling about it but so far none of it worked and I am almost out of ideas. It works fine when using the static variables that I was using though. I included the bean xml to web.xml through `<context-param>` tags and it is being detected.

Comment: @Wax, if autowired doesn't work, that means that something wrong with your configuration.

Comment: I managed to get it working now. Turns out I need this included in my xml. `<bean class ="org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor"/>`

Thank you man!